# trying to dynamically name and later reference dataframe name as a variable, getting error 'SyntaxError: can't assign to function call'

Tags: python, pandas

```
#define list of fields to run match for

fieldlist = ['MATTER NUMBER','MATTER NAME','CLAIM NUMBER LISTING']

#loop through each field in fieldlist
for field in fieldlist:
    #define dfname as the field with spaces replaced with underscores
    dfname = '{}'.format(field.replace(' ','_'))
    #create df with dfname
    '{}'.format(dfname) = checkdf['{}'.format(field)].dropna()
```

the error is on the last line. I also tried:

```
'{}'.format(dfname) = checkdf['{}'.format(field)].dropna()
```

edit: apologies if this was confusing. I'm attempting to create dataframe names and columns associated with each field in fieldlist from checkdf. checkdf is an existing dataframe that contains the columns listed in fieldlist . I was attempting to use the format function to input the dataframe name (dfname) and column name (field) in the last line.
For example, I'd like python to read the first loop as:

```
dfname = MATTER_NUMBER
MATTER_NUMBER = checkdf['MATTER_NUMBER']
```

Comment: Yes that line is broken.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm coming from a place of caring and believe me there is zero judgement in this comment.  You would be well served by doing some online python tutorials.  Just google "python tutorial".  What you are doing wrong is obvious to most of us and would be to you as well if you finished a tutorial.  Unfortunately, Stackoverflow isn't a place to receive basic tutoring.  At least not in my opinion.  Doesn't matter, a tutorial or two is what you need.

Comment: Stephen - I added some extra information, maybe that will help with understanding what I'm trying to do? Thanks!

piRSquared - I'm happy to take a look at any tutorials that address this issue if you're aware of any. The reason I'm trying to loop through and dynamically name these dataframes is that I have about 100 lines of code (string manipulation for the most part) that I'd like to apply to multiple columns from the parent dataframe (checkdf) once this is settled. Trying to avoid code duplication if I can. If you can think of a better way to go about it conceptually I'm all ears

Answer (score -1):

You can't assign a new value to `'{}'.format(dfname)` it is what it is (you cannot modify what a function returns by using `=` for each possible input for the function), a function call that returns a string. Change the part before the `=` in the last line:

```
'{}'.format(dfname) = checkdf['{}'.format(field)].dropna()
```

I am not sure what you are trying to do here, so I cannot help you with this.

---

**Edit**: you probably want:

```
dfname = checkdf['{}'.format(field)].dropna()
```

In the last line.

Comment: I added some additional information, maybe that might help you understand what I'm trying to do? Thanks